# How do I query a postgresql Time field in ActiveRecord/Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

My database schema includes a `time` field:

```
create_table "my_model", force: true do |t|
  t.time     "at"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

I've tried to query it with something like this:

```
MyModel.where(at: Time.now)
```

The problem is that will never return anything even though a record exists with the same hour, minute and seconds as right now, because `Time.now` includes the year, month and day. At least I think that's why it never returns back anything?

How do I query `MyModel`'s `at` field?

Comment: How did you solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think is too late now but you can do this:

```
timenow = Time.now
MyModel.where(at: timenow.strftime("%I:%M%p"))
```